# Python Wand change tiff to min-is-white

Tags: python, imagemagick, tiff, wand

I need to convert files to tiff where photometric is set "min-is-white" (white is zero) to comply with the required standards. I'm using Wand to interact with Photomagick but every I save a bilevel tiff file, it creates a min-is-black.

How can I get Wand to saves it where White is Zero? Is it even possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Python, and I can't understand the documentation for Wand. However, the thing you are looking for is a `define`, or an `option` which would be specified on the ImageMagick command-line as `-define quantum:polarity=min-is-white`. So if you can find out how to set defines or options, e.g. `-define jpeg:extent=100KB` you should be able to do the same thing with the polarity. Hope that helps. @emcconville will know how to do it...

Comment: That's exactly right  @MarkSetchell !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark's comments are correct. You need to set the `-define` property for ImageMagick.

For [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), you'll have to extent the core `wand.api.library` to connect MagickWand's C-API `MagickSetOption` method.

```py
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_char_p
from wand.api import library
from wand.image import Image

# Tell python about the MagickSetOption method
library.MagickSetOption.argtypes = [c_void_p,  # MagickWand * wand
                                    c_char_p,  # const char * option
                                    c_char_p]  # const char * value

# Read source image
with Image(filename="/path/to/source.tiff") as image:
    # -define quantum:polarity=min-is-white
    library.MagickSetOption(image.wand,          # MagickWand
                            "quantum:polarity",  # option
                            "min-is-white")      # value
    # Write min-is-white image
    image.save(filename="/path/to/min-is-white.tiff")
```

You can verify the resulting image with the `identify` utility.

```sh
identify -verbose /path/to/min-is-white.tiff | grep photometric
#=> tiff:photometric: min-is-white
```

Comment: Yay! I was just about to post that I figured out the answer and I see that we came to the same solution. Awesome