# Sliced tiff image gets bigger with python Wand

Tags: python, wand

I have a .tif file that has 10 pages. I want to create a sub-image containing only pages 2-7, but the produced file is much bigger than the orginal. It should be smaller. What would you suggest? Here is my code:

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='test.tif') as original:
    with Image() as sub_image:
        sub_image.sequence.extend(original.sequence[2:7])
        sub_image.save(filename='sub.tif')
```

Original: 3mb

Sub: 50mb (!)

EDIT: Here a sample source file : [tif file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3y0c8x0oe1u4eba/test.tif?dl=0)

Comment: Could you link to the image file so that the code can be tested?

Comment: I just tested this on a tiff file I had lying around: original =  881K, sub =  442K. What encoding does the original use? Perhaps `wand` has saved without compression while the original used e.g. JPEG or LZW?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot post the picture because it contains sensitive information. However it is 10 A4 pages scanned from an office printer. Based on what you said I tried to output original.compression and it gave me 'group4'. However, the sub_image has the same compression. Maybe I can scan something else and post the tif file.

Comment: I just added a sample scan you can try with.

Comment: Now I get 3.0M Original and 3.6M sub.tif.. so not quite as drastic but still strange... lemme see if I can find out why...

Comment: Ok using imagemagick I was able to find that my original has jpg compression and sub_image has None compression. However inside python I see 'group4'. Do you know how to enable jpg compression before saving ? Even if I add sub_image.compression = 'jpeg', it doesn't change my output size.

Comment: Both seem to use JPEG compression, and the underlying data is MUCH bigger (332MB original, 166MB sub).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106717/discussion-between-emanuel-and-jmetz).

Comment: This could be an issue with your `wand` / `imagemagick` install - as mentioned, the result on my machine (linux) was that both files were relativley small

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot at play in the TIFF file. Try the following in the command line.

```
convert 'test.tif[2-7]' \
        -define 'tiff:rows-per-strip=3504' \
        -colorspace YCBCR \
        -alpha remove \
        -auto-level \
        -compress JPEG \
        -endian LSB \
        -depth 8 \
        output.tif
```

All options above match the original file except `rows-per-strip`. The original document has `rows-per-strip` of 3507; which is not a multiple of 8 (don't know what impact that would have).

The majority of the options are supported by [wand](/questions/tagged/wand), and should be implemented / respected in your calling script.

For `-define 'tiff:rows-per-strip=3504'`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802002/438117).